# Error when installing ImageMagick-last on Amazon Linux from the Remi Repo

Tags: amazon-ec2, imagemagick

On my Amazon Linux AMI I'm trying to install ImageMagick-last from the remi repo. I run the command

```
sudo yum install ImageMagick-last.x86_64
```

but I get the errors

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libImath.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libIlmImf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librsvg-2.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libIex.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libIlmThread.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libHalf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: ImageMagick-last-libs-6.8.7.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: ImageMagick-last conflicts with ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-6.12.amzn1.x86_64
```

I have searched for solutions, but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve these dependencies. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you may already have a older version installed. Try removing it and then pointing at the newest repo version.

```
yum remove package ImageMagick
yum --enablerepo=remi install ImageMagick-last
```

Then reinstall

If that does not work you can download the rpms for each dependency and install them manually. You can get them from rpmfind.net [There's the first.](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libImath.so.6%28%29%2864bit%29) Just wget the rpm and then install it.

```
wget "packageurl"
rpm –ivh "packagename"
```

If you run into any dependency requirements for X-Window or GTK you'll need to [compile from source with the --without-x flag.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php)

**FYI** - AWS Linux is really just CentOS pointed at Amazons repos with Cloud Init and other goodies pre-installed. So it helps just to search for the CentOS solution

**Update** ARolek created a [gist](http://gist.github.com/ARolek/9199329) with instructions for compiling from source.

**Update Feb. 2017** Remi doesn't have `ImageMagick-last` anymore. It's now called `ImageMagick7`:
`yum --enablerepo=remi install ImageMagick7`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just tried this, and I'm still getting the same error (I did have an old version of ImageMagick installed) Here is a link to all the output on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/hz8NfQzz. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like this is broken for others as well. (this is 6 days old) http://pastebin.com/wJcRqazV can you try an older version?

Comment: I think that is actually another pastebin I made while trying to get some help in #centos on freenode. No PHP stuff installed. Installing each rpm is making some headway. I did hit an issue with librsvg-2. Check out the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/98UeVPqU

Comment: so you think I should just skip broken?

Comment: your going to have to google around for a headless install, this package might help ImageMagick-devel

Comment: I was able to compile from source with the config param --without-x. pointing out the need for a headless install helped me find the solution ;-)

Comment: I added a line on that flag for posterity.

Comment: here is a link to a gist I put together with instructions for compiling from source: https://gist.github.com/ARolek/9199329

Comment: I put that in the answer with credit to you. Safe keeping in case they cull comments from this chatty question.

Comment: How can I avoid doing "make" every time I want to spawn a new EC2-instance?

Comment: why don't you install it to a base ec2-instance and then take a snapshot. you can then start new instances from the snapshot.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html Or, if you are creating instances programmatically can create a cloud init script and send it as the user-data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the latest you can borrow from this script that I currently use to spin up new hosts using Elastic Beanstalk

https://gist.github.com/primeobsession/f9d30c5ebc8b0486de14